# why the error "undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create" in IDE?

Tags: c++

I got two error's  `undefined reference to _imp__pthread_create` and `undefined reference to _imp__pthread_join` in Dev C++ in windows IDE, I am using dev c++ 5.4.1. Why this error? How can I resolve this?  Could somebody shed some light? Thank you verymuch for your time!!

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<pthread.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    void *uss_thread(void*){
        
        cout<<"hello";
    }
    
    main()
    {
         pthread_t tid1;    
         pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, &uss_thread, NULL);
         pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
    }
```

Comment: Do yourself two favours: 1. switch to a decent compiler. 2. use C++11 `std::thread`s.

Comment: Should this question be rolled back to the original? I was searching for the `make (e=5): Access is denied.` and found this question but it was altered after answering and the answer does not make sense at all with the contents of current question.

Comment: @drescherjm now the answer and duplicate does not make any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't link with lib `pthread`.

Download [DevPack](http://oopthread.googlecode.com/files/pthreads_w32-2.8.0-1aj.DevPak)

- Install it in Dev C++
- Create new Project in Dev C++
- After that go to Project menu -> Project Option -> In that select
  "Parameter Tab"
- Select "add Library or object" option
- SelectIt "libpthreadGC2.a" file from installation directory of Dev c++ : It will be in LIB directory.
- Press Ok

Good Lucks !

Comment: Although this question has already sort of been merged into that other one, I just wanted to inform you that the maintained version of Dev-C++ currently provides OpenMP by default, so that you only need to pass -lgomp and -fopenmp (no need to fiddle with packages and libraries): http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Comment: Thanks @Orwell for the info, but i work on Unix/Cli so not IDE ;)